# iOS 8, How to use device for development?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xcode6

I have a new iPad Retina and I'd like to use it for development with Xamarin Studio and XCode 6.  In the past, with XCode 5 you simply connect the device and click the button that says "Use for Development".  But XCode 6 doesn't have that button anymore and when I try to build my application to the device in Xamarin Studio i get the error message saying "Could not install the application '/Users/jzacherl/Projects/CyCom/CyCom/CyCom/bin/iPhone/Debug/CyCom.app' on the device iPad: Your application failed code-signing checks.  Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids.   Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning profile (error: 0xe8008015).
".

My application should support both iOS 7 and iOS 8.  I've tried changing target deployment to and from 7 & 8 and I've tried restarting my mac/device and build/cleaning my project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot, this is driving me crazy. Why take away the user for dev button??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register a device with your Developer ID at:

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action

(You will have to be logged into the developer site to do so.)

After that, everything should work fine. You can get your device's UDID from iTunes.

Comment: Is that a new requirement?  I never had to do that in the past with XCode 5, I always just plugged it in and clicked "Use for Development" and I could build directly to the device without having to go to the Apple Developer site.

Comment: I don't think it's a new requirement. I also don't know why the 'Use For Development' button is so inconsistent (seemingly) in Xcode 6, but the way I suggested doing it is what I've always done. It might not even fix your problem, but it worked fine for me - try it and let us know if it works!

Comment: It does work, but I really didn't want to use 1 of my limited 100 devices on this device because I'm saving the others for beta testers.  I swear in the past I was able to just plug in a random iPad, click use for development and build with a Developer Provisioning profile...

Comment: To build and run apps on an iOS device, you would be using one of your 100 devices whether you clicked 'Use For Development' or not, as far as I know. Unless I am quite mistaken, the 'Use For Development' button just automates the process of registering your device through the same service that the website provides.

Comment: Also, if you want beta testers, check out [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/Testflight/).

Comment: @LampShade when you click the `use for development` Xcode adds the device to your portal and it **will** take up 1 of the 100 development devices you have within your account.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification on the details everyone.  Yes, now that test flight supports thousands of testers/users I'm on board there too.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @Ata It was accepted as an answer months ago and directly addressed the asker's issue. In what way does this not answer the question?

Comment: Where is the "use for development " button?

Comment: @Ata The question is 'how to use device for development', not 'where is the "Use For Development" button'.

Comment: My reason was that option might always have been there (adding uuid from apple site). But he couldn't figure out what happened to the option in xcode like it used to. Maybe its wrong

Comment: the link is useless now. it no longer has a device list or in fact anything that couldn't be found from google

Answer (score 7):

Despite the hints here and elsewhere, it took me awhile to find the exact solution. So, for others who are new to Xcode:

The navbar at the top of the main Xcode 6 window has a triangle run/play button, a square stop button, the app's name, then a target name, e.g. "iPhone 6" for one of the simulator options. **The target name is actually a drop-down menu!** That is where to select your actual device.

Now click the triangle button to build & run. Likely result: "No non-expired provisioning profiles are installed" with a button to "Fix Issue". Click that, wait a bit ... done!

Hat tip (and screenshots): http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-teach/how-to-prepare/ios-device-provisioning/#loc-provisioning-easy

Cross reference to a later question with a more descriptive title: [There is NO Use for Development in Xcode's Organizer window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585840/there-is-no-use-for-development-in-xcodes-organizer-window)

Comment: And if there is a mismatch between your iOS device's version and Xcode, it will be in a part of the menu called "ineligible" devices, and you'll need to upgrade Xcode before you can use that device with it.

Comment: In XCode 8, we have to open the project editor, "General" tab, "Signing" section, and with the iPhone connected, it will show a button "create and install certificate".

Answer (score 3):

Try building and deploying an Xcode app and see what happens.

I believe Xcode will popup a helpful dialog if you need to do something Xcode can't do automatically.

Comment: I believe this is right. It's hard to get to myself into a zero state in order to test, but what I find is that if you just try to build-and-run on your device, Xcode puts up a couple of dialogs offering to help and does all the work for you - registers the device at the Member Center, creates the universal provisioning profile. It even creates the development certificate if needed!

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to register the *UDID* of the device in iOS member center and add with the provisioning profile and install the provisioning profile
- In versions of Xcode prior to Xcode 6, you can connect the device to your computer over USB, open *Xcode -> Organizer* and select *Use for Development*.
- Use for Development was removed from Xcode in Xcode 6 and later. It is no longer possible to do this for devices using Xcode 6 or later, even with the Devices page
- Try going to *Window->Devices*. You should see your attached device in the list so *right click* on the device and select *Show Provisioning Profiles*.It will show a window where you can add your profile.

After that you will be able to install your app in that device.