# There is NO Use for Development in Xcode's Organizer window

Tags: ios, xcode

I signed up with Apple's $99 development for iOS program today.
Under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in Xcode, no matter what I click on it tells me to:

> Connect your device to your Mac and click Use for Development in Xcode's Organizer window. Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your iOS Developer Program membership and Xcode will automatically generate your certificates.

In Xcode 6.1, I go to Window then Organizer and I only see projects and Archives. No device next to it and no button to click "Use For Development" and I have my iPhone connected.

Funny thing is I already connected my iPhone app game to work on an iPhone device yet I still have no button to click on "Use For Development".

What am I missing? This is all I'm being told to do by Apple and I don't see the button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8, How to use device for development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999167/ios-8-how-to-use-device-for-development)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Xcode 6.1 removed 'Devices' from 'Organizer'.

Now you can go to **Window > Devices** to get all the connected and registered devices.

Comment: in an effort to reduce clutter caused by duplicates, you should cite the duplicate rather than answering the question.

Comment: @jww I'm sorry that this happened, I thought it was an obvious question, I had the same problem and it was an easy fix. I didn't see the duplicate comment.

Comment: The question might be a dup, but this answer is better and simpler than the answer on the original...

Comment: unfortunately going to Window > Devices doesn't show the registered devices just the connected devices. Xcode is naturally worse than before. Now you have to manually register your device.

Comment: Sorry I am downvoting because Window > Devices does not have anywhere to generate your certificates. Could the answer be updated for this?

Answer (score 10):

What I find, although it's hard to get into a total zero state in order to test, is that if you just connect the device to the computer and try to build-and-run with the device as destination, Xcode puts up a dialog offering to help you and, if you accept, it does all the work: it registers the device at the member center and downloads the universal provisioning profile.

So there is no "Use For Development" button because there doesn't need to be one: it was superfluous.

Comment: This is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

automatic signing

Automatic signing is a target setting that allows Xcode to manage signing assets for you. The signing settings are located in the General pane under the heading Signing in the project editor. To enable automatic signing, select “Automatically manage signing.”

If you enable automatic signing, Xcode does the following for you when needed:

Creates your certificates and signing identities

Registers connected devices

Creates and edits App IDs

Manages provisioning profiles

Edits the entitlements and information property list files

If you choose manual signing, you’ll need to sign in to your developer account at developer.apple.com/account to perform some of these steps yourself.

Important: All targets in a bundle should use the same signing identity. If you select automatic signing for one target, you should select automatic signing for all targets in your project.

screenshot for more details

[image]

Comment: ...except when it doesn't...  rargh.

Comment: Target Setting was missing for me, so the screenshot was a help to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Automatic Signing:

As of XCode 9.3, there is no more dialog, as in [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) answer. Instead, with your device connected, review your Build Target(s) page - under Signing, there is a "Register Device" button. Use that to have XCode automatically handle adding the new device and updating your provisioning profile.

### Manual Signing:

If you're not allowing XCode to manage signing for you, or if you have multiple devices to register, then Manual Signing is the way to go. In Window > "Devices & Simulators" > Devices, look for the UDID (aka Identifier) for your connected device (40-character alphanumeric string). Copy that string, and keep it handy.

Log in to your Apple Developer Account, go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Devices. Click the "+" to add one (or multiple) devices, and paste in the device name and the UDID/Identifier you copied earlier.